# Python 3.7 - CSV - Remove quotes from value, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the " sign from the csv file I'm creating, but it either gives me an error: "_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set" or it gives me the quotechar='"' every first character and latest one.

I'm running 3.7 Python and I tried changing my code with the below changes:

```
passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n' ,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        #passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,)
        #passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',' ,lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

def print_dict(d,site_id):
with open('passphrases.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n' ,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    #passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,)
    #passphrase_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',' ,lineterminator='\n', quotechar='|')

    for idx, val in enumerate(d['data']):
        x = (u'{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(val['id'],
                                               val['Name'],
                                               val['domain'],
                                               val['Version'],
                                               val['lastLoggedIn'],
                                               val['networkInterfaces'][0]['inet'][0],
                                               val['id2'],
                                               passphrase(val['id'], site_id)
                                               ))
        print(x)
        passphrase_writer.writerow([x])
```

The results in the print are good:

`54356,tomer-a36,WORKGROUP,2.,tom,192.168.30.133,eafa2eb,DREAM`

However, the csv file will have:
`"54356,tomer-a36,WORKGROUP,2.,tom,192.168.30.133,eafa2eb,DREAM"`

I wish to remove the extra "

note - when changing the `quotechar='|'`, I'm getting:
`|54356,tomer-a36,WORKGROUP,2.,tom,192.168.30.133,eafa2eb,DREAM|`

trying to set `quotechar=''` gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it & mixing custom formatting with built-in `csv` module

You're passing a list of an already formatted argument, with the separator as `,`. `csv` module has to quote it to make it remain a single "cell" because default `csv` separator is already `,`. `csv` module has a safety built-in to avoid losing/corrupting data: not quoting data would make 1 cell with commas in it indistinguishable from several cells separated with commas.

Instead, just write your argument as a `tuple` of your data and stop building `x` using `str.format`.

```
for val in d['data']:
    passphrase_writer.writerow((val['id'],
                           val['Name'],
                           val['domain'],
                           val['Version'],
                           val['lastLoggedIn'],
                           val['networkInterfaces'][0]['inet'][0],
                           val['id2'],
                           passphrase(val['id'], site_id)
                           ))
```

Since your data never contains `,` (are you sure of that? seems that `passphrase` could, actually) you don't have to worry about quotes being inserted.

And if there were (`passphrase` could be a good candidate), `csv.reader` would be able to parse them and remove them to unserialize your data (as Excel would do too). Don't try to read & parse back the file manually splitting with `,`, use `csv` module again.